# Synonyms for "having a property"

Tags: idioms, synonyms, technical

When writing a mathematical text one often wants to express that a certain object has a certain property, i.e.:

"Object A has property X."

Since this formulation gets boring if used too many times, I would like to know of some alternative formulations.

For instance I understand one could say:

"Object A enjoys property X."

Would the following be correct?

"Object A carries property X."

Are there any other possible variations?

Comment: I've seen *exhibits property X*, but not *carries*...

Comment: If it's a mathematical text, consistency can be a good thing. Variety can be interesting, but the anthropomorphosis of Object A looks weird in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- exhibits
- displays
- shows
- fulfills
- satisfies
- includes
- embodies
- maintains
- incorporates??? (really starting to get leery now)

Honestly, though, none are great.  Certainly does get very tiring using the same words when writing scientifically... but I think I'm still with Lawrence.  You'll go back later, and it'll just sound so very forced, and like you're obnoxiously trying to stand out, or be different for the sake of being different.  And it'll take away from the subject at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your opinion on the matter. I think I will stick with "has property X" and only use "exhibits" when I need another word to make a sentence less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

"Possesses"
Regardless of the options available, it would probably be worth heeding to consistency in scientific or other rigorous analyses.